# Is it possible to customize the GParted toolbar so that the icons include text?

Tags: gparted

I installed GParted 0.12.1 in ubuntu. There is no text description under the toolbar icons. Is there a way to display text under the icons in the toolbar as can be seen on the various tutorial web pages and the GParted page at Wikipedia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install dconf-editor (`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`) and run it you can change this default.

Simply navigate to org/gnome/desktop/interface and change the value that says toolbar-style to "both" (by default it is both-horiz).

Do note, however, that this is a change that affects all applications, not just GParted.

Answer (score 0):

Githlar has the right answer, but like he said it will affect all of your applications. If you do not want to make that change, you might be satisfied with different icons.

Installing **unity-tweak-tool** will allow you to change your icon theme. Gnome-tweak-tool will work as well but I don't like it nearly as much.

`sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`

Find and download icons. I like getting them from [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xsortmode=high&page=0&xcontentmode=120x121). Then unpack them to /usr/share/icons.

Now you just launch the tweak tool and change your icons. This way you can find some icons that help you identify the functions of gparted without adding text to all of your programs' title bars.